# Signed permutations and $ SO(n) $

Tags: finite-groups, lie-groups, coxeter-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}\DeclareMathOperator\O{O}\DeclareMathOperator\SU{SU}\DeclareMathOperator\Lift{Lift}$The subgroup of $ \SO(n) $ of determinant-$1$ signed permutations has order $ n!2^n/2 $. I will call this group $ W_n $.

Question:

Is it true that $ W_n $ is a maximal proper closed subgroup of $ SO(n) $ if and only if $ n $ is not a power of $ 2 $?

Context:
$$
W_3 \cong S_4
$$
is isomorphic to the symmetric group on 4 letters. It is a maximal proper closed subgroup of $ \SO(3) $.

It is also true that there are no closed subgroups of $ \SO(5) $ containing $ W_5 $ and none in $ \SO(6) $ containing $ W_6 $.

$$
W_2 \cong C_4
$$
is the cyclic group of order 4. It is not maximal. The infinitely many cyclic subgroups of order $ 4m $ all contain $ W_2 $.

And for $ W_4 $ we have a chain of strict containments
$$
W_4 \subsetneq \Lift(S_4 \times S_4) \subsetneq \SO(4)
$$
where $\Lift$ denotes the Lift through the double cover $ \SO(4) \to \SO(3) \times \SO(3) $.

I think that $ W_n $  fails to be maximal for every $ n=2^k $ a power of $ 2 $. Indeed it seems to me that $ W_{2^k} $ normalizes a certain extraspecial subgroup $ E \subset SO(2^k) $ of order $ 2^{2k+1} $. The full normalizer of $ E $ is generated by the signed permutations together with tensor products involving
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1 \end{bmatrix}
$$

Comment: Isn't $W(D_n)$ itself a closed subgroup?

Comment: @KentaS Ok I went through and added "proper" and "properly" in a bunch of places